# How to add two dataset to one df's single column?

Tags: r

How to convert a1 and a2

```
a1 <- c(1:3)
a2 <- c(4:6)
```

as single column in a new dataset?

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, data.frame(a = c(a1, a2))

Comment: @evdstat It really looks like a pure R question that would be better served on Stack Overflow, and I'll migrate it for you. (You'll need to register your account and associate your CV and SO accounts so that you'll get notifications whenever a new reply is posted.)

Answer (score 5):

You could do:

```
a3 <- c(a1, a2)
```

which would give you a vector, or

```
a3 <- as.data.frame(c(a1, a2))
```

which gives you a data frame